# Is AWS Timestream a good solution to store an audit log?

Tags: amazon-timestream

My application offers a WRITE API that writes and deletes data to DynamoDB, and we want to store an audit log of what happened, like this:

> timestamp, account, ADD/DELETE, information

We want to be able to satisfy queries like:

- For account X, give me all events
- For account X, give me all events where `information=Y`
- For account X, give me all events where `information=Y` and `timestamp>Z`

Would AWS Timestream be a good candidate solution for this? It can support queries like

```
SELECT * FROM "database"."table" 
WHERE time between ago(15m) and now() 
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

which would be fitting our use case.

But it says on the documentation:

> The ability to analyze massive amounts of data quickly and efficiently is one of Timestream’s greatest strengths. A single query executing over terabytes or even petabytes of data may have thousands of machines working on it all at the same time.

We don't need this ability. We are not analyzing data, we just need to retrieve it.

Also:

> Timestream offers two data stores – an in-memory store and a cost-effective magnetic store

I don't think we need the in-memory store, as we don't care too much for speed of the response.

Comment: https://www.timescale.com/blog/timescaledb-vs-amazon-timestream-6000x-higher-inserts-175x-faster-queries-220x-cheaper/

Comment: Hi, did you get answer for this question ?
what approach did you go with ?

Comment: @Himz we are using DynamoDB transactions to store the event itself in one table and the changelog in another table.

Comment: Yeah, i am also leaning to the solution of using DynamoDB. I am thinking of single table design for it. Just curious, why the decision to keep changelog in separate table, rather than using single table design in DDB.

Comment: @Himz in our specific scenario our main table has many indexes. We don't want to index the changelog data